# How to make R base plots larger inside boundary box?

Tags: r, plot, resize, zooming, margins

I am creating two plots in R, arranged with one over another. The issue is that the plot is very small within the boundary box, and I don't know how to "zoom in" essentially. Changing the margins only affects the size of the boundary box, not the little plot on the inside. Any help would be appreciated as I'm very new to this!

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(1,1,1,1))

plot(G_nwr,axes=FALSE,main="Non-weighted")
plot(boundary,add=TRUE)
points(G$utm_x,G$utm_y,pch=16,cex=0.2)
plot(roads_clip,add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=0.5)
plot(buildings_clip,add=TRUE,col="gray80")
plot(creeks_clip,add=TRUE,col="lightskyblue",lwd=2)
plot(railways_clip,add=TRUE,col="purple1",lwd=2)
plot(water_clip,add=TRUE,col="steelblue1")
legend("topright",inset=0.05, cex=0.8,
       c("Canadian Goose","Road","Building","Creek","Railway","Water Body"),pch=c(16,NA,15,NA,15,NA),lty=c(NA,1,NA,1,NA,1),col=c("black","red","gray80","lightskyblue","purple1","steelblue1"))
```

[image: Example picture here]

Comment: Could you please post the code with which you generated the graph. That would help bring some traction to this question.

Comment: We do not have access to `G_nwr` nor the other variables so we won't be able to reproduce this to help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't provide the actual data I am working with, as it is not my property. I thought maybe it was a margins issue or there was another argument I could just add that someone might know about. Thank you for taking a look anyways :)